# TITokenField with only contacts tokens

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using TITokenField for a send message view.
My problem is that this component allow user to insert any type of token, even not in the source array of contacts.
I want user have to choose contacts only in that array and not type any random text in it.
Any good idea (and code) to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

TITokenFieldView now has a property called forcePickSearchResult. If you set it to YES, text typed into the field will be used to filter the source array but it won't be tokenized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the willAddToken method to check whether the token is allowed to be added to the token field. Implement the following method on your delegate class. The method is from the TITokenFieldDelegate protocol.

```
- (BOOL)tokenField:(TITokenField *)tokenField willAddToken:(TIToken *)token
{
    if(someStatementCheck)
    {
         // do something as the token will be added to the field
         return YES;
     } else {
         // do something when not allowed to add token
         return NO;
     }
}
```